# Flutter using different initialRoute

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an mobile app, that I want to save the pages with shared_preferences. But this is not the problem.
In my main app, I want to set the initialRoute property the latest page that is viewed after exit. But It just return the main route '/'.
Here is the code:

```
class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  var _currentRoute;

 _getCurrentRoute() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _currentRoute = preferences.getString('LastScreenRoute');
      if (_currentRoute == null) {
        _currentRoute = '/';
        preferences.setString('LastScreenRoute', _currentRoute);
      }
    });
    print(_currentRoute); // result here is true and It's the current page
}

@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
  _getCurrentRoute();
  print(_currenRoute); // but here It's null!
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialRoute: _currentRoute,
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => FirstPage(),
      '/RegisterScreen': (context) => Register(),
      '/LoginScreen': (context) => Login(),
      '/HomeScreen': (context) => HomePage(),
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: `print(_currenRoute);` in `initState()` may be called before `_getCurrentRoute()`.

Make the `getCurrentRoute()` method return a route and print that instead of the global variable `_currentRoute`.

Comment: print is not the problem. I want to use the **_currentRoute** that I've got in **_getCurrentRoute()** in the **initialRoute** property. But the **_currentRoute** in front of **initialRoute** is null and it automatically became '/' all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_getCurrentRoute()` is `async`, so doesn't finish immediately. That's why `_currentRoute` is still null in the line with the comment; `_getCurrentRoute()` hasn't finished yet, so hasn't set `_currentRoute`.

You need to wait for it to get set before making your `MaterialApp`, for example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return (_currentRoute == null) ? Container() : MaterialApp(
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that.